# javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf

i'm working on a project using jsf,spring and hibernate.
i get an exception in one case, but i don't really understand the reason why i'm getting this problem.
can you give me an idea what i did wrong

```
 javax.el.ELException: /views/emissionsa.xhtml @102,171 actionListener="#{emission1Bean.payer()}": org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
eeeeeeeeeeeee
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at net.vo.Salaire_$$_javassist_5.getPersonnel(Salaire_$$_javassist_5.java)
    at controller.Emission1Bean.payer(Emission1Bean.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 34 more

25-Jun-2014 23:42:28.209 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-134] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at net.vo.Salaire_$$_javassist_5.getPersonnel(Salaire_$$_javassist_5.java)
    at controller.Emission1Bean.payer(Emission1Bean.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:277)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

emissionsa.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <style>
            .p tr,.p td
            {
                border : none;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body style="background-color: #ECF3FD;">
         <h:graphicImage value="../../images/header.jpg" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;"></h:graphicImage>
    <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable id="display" var="listeEmissions" value="#{emission1Bean.listeEmissions}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:10px" rowKey="#{listeEmissions.dateEmission}" selection="#{emission1Bean.emission}" selectionMode="single">
       <f:facet name="header">
           Liste des factures émises
       </f:facet>

       <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowEdit}" />
       <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{dtEditView.onRowCancel}"/>

       <p:column headerText="Date Emission">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeEmissions.dateEmission}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{listeEmissions.dateEmission}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="N° Ordre de paiement">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeEmissions.nop}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeEmissions.nop}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="N° Bordereau">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeEmissions.nbordereau}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeEmissions.nbordereau}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
      <p:column style="width:32px" headerText="Modifier">
          <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"/>

       </p:column>
        <p:column style="width:32px" headerText="Supprimer">
            <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" action="#{emission1Bean.delete()}" process="@this" update=":form:display">
               <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{emission1Bean.emission}" value="#{listeEmissions}" />
    </p:commandLink>
       </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
            <p:commandButton value="Payer le salaire" update="emissionDetail" oncomplete="PF('emissionDialog').show()" />
             <p:dialog header="Paiement du salaire" widgetVar="emissionDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
        <p:panel id="emissionDetail" style="border:none;">
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty emission1Bean.emission}" columnClasses="label,value" style="border:none;">

<p:accordionPanel>
                    <p:tab title="Payer le salaire">

                    <h:panelGrid styleClass="p" columns="2"  cellpadding="5">


                <h:outputText value="Date paiement: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{emission1Bean.datePaiement}"/>

                 <h:outputText value="Compte Bancaire: " />
                 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{compteBancaireBean.idCompte}"  >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--Séléctionner un fournisseur" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{compteBancaireBean.listeCompteBancaires}" var="compte" 
                       itemValue="#{compte.idCompte}" itemLabel="#{compte.libelleCompte}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{compteBancaireBean.submit()}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="N° Chèque: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{emission1Bean.ncheque}"/>

                <h:outputText value="N° Virement: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{emission1Bean.nvirement}"/>

                <h:outputText value="N° Avis de virement: " />
                <p:inputText value="#{emission1Bean.navis}"/>
              </h:panelGrid>

                    </p:tab>


        </p:accordionPanel>





                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="Valider" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" update="display" onclick="emissionDialog.hide();" actionListener="#{emission1Bean.payer()}"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Annuler" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w" onclick="emissionDialog.hide();"/>


        </p:panel>
    </p:dialog>  
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Emission1Bean.java

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class Emission1Bean {

    @Autowired
    private SalaireMetier salaireMetier;
    @Autowired
    private EmissionMetier emissionMetier;
    @Autowired
    private PaiementMetier paiementMetier;
    @Autowired
    private FactureMetier factureMetier;
    @Autowired
    private ComptebancaireMetier comptebancaireMetier;
    private List<Emission> listeEmissions;
    private Emission emission;
    private String dateEmission;
    private Salaire salaire;
    private Integer nop;
    private Integer nbordereau;
    private int idCompte;
    private String datePaiement;
    private Comptebancaire comptebancaire;
    private Archive archive;
    private Integer ncheque;
    private Integer nvirement;
    private Integer navis;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        listeEmissions = emissionMetier.getAllEmissionsSa();
    }
    public void payer()
    {
        Emission e = emissionMetier.getEmission(getEmission().getDateEmission());
        SalaireId id = new SalaireId(e.getSalaire().getPersonnel().getCin(),e.getSalaire().getMois().getMois());
        Salaire s = salaireMetier.getSalaire(id);
        Paiement p = new Paiement();
        p.setDatePaiement(getDatePaiement());
        p.setSalaire(s);
        int c = CompteBancaireBean.submit();
        Comptebancaire compte = comptebancaireMetier.getComptebancaire(c);
        p.setComptebancaire(compte);
        p.setNavis(getNavis());
        p.setNcheque(getNcheque());
        p.setNvirement(getNvirement());
        paiementMetier.insert(p);
    }
    public int submit()
    {
        System.out.println(idCompte);
        return idCompte;
    }
    public void delete(){
        Emission e = emissionMetier.getEmission(getEmission().getDateEmission());
        emissionMetier.delete(getEmission().getDateEmission());
        listeEmissions.remove(emission);
        emission = null;
        SalaireId id1 = new SalaireId(e.getSalaire().getPersonnel().getCin(),e.getSalaire().getMois().getMois());
        Salaire sa = salaireMetier.getSalaire(id1);
        sa.setEtatSalaire("engage");
        salaireMetier.update(sa);
    }

    public Salaire getSalaire() {
        return salaire;
    }

    public void setSalaire(Salaire salaire) {
        this.salaire = salaire;
    }

    public ComptebancaireMetier getComptebancaireMetier() {
        return comptebancaireMetier;
    }

    public void setComptebancaireMetier(ComptebancaireMetier comptebancaireMetier) {
        this.comptebancaireMetier = comptebancaireMetier;
    }

    public PaiementMetier getPaiementMetier() {
        return paiementMetier;
    }

    public void setPaiementMetier(PaiementMetier paiementMetier) {
        this.paiementMetier = paiementMetier;
    }

    public FactureMetier getFactureMetier() {
        return factureMetier;
    }

    public void setFactureMetier(FactureMetier factureMetier) {
        this.factureMetier = factureMetier;
    }

    public int getIdCompte() {
        return idCompte;
    }

    public void setIdCompte(int idCompte) {
        this.idCompte = idCompte;
    }

    public String getDatePaiement() {
        return datePaiement;
    }

    public void setDatePaiement(String datePaiement) {
        this.datePaiement = datePaiement;
    }

    public Comptebancaire getComptebancaire() {
        return comptebancaire;
    }

    public void setComptebancaire(Comptebancaire comptebancaire) {
        this.comptebancaire = comptebancaire;
    }

    public Archive getArchive() {
        return archive;
    }

    public void setArchive(Archive archive) {
        this.archive = archive;
    }

    public Integer getNcheque() {
        return ncheque;
    }

    public void setNcheque(Integer ncheque) {
        this.ncheque = ncheque;
    }

    public Integer getNvirement() {
        return nvirement;
    }

    public void setNvirement(Integer nvirement) {
        this.nvirement = nvirement;
    }

    public Integer getNavis() {
        return navis;
    }

    public void setNavis(Integer navis) {
        this.navis = navis;
    }

    public Emission getEmission() {
        return emission;
    }

    public void setEmission(Emission emission) {
        this.emission = emission;
    }


    public List<Emission> getListeEmissions() {
        return listeEmissions;
    }

    public void setListeEmissions(List<Emission> listeEmissions) {
        this.listeEmissions = listeEmissions;
    }

    public EmissionMetier getEmissionMetier() {
        return emissionMetier;
    }

    public void setEmissionMetier(EmissionMetier emissionMetier) {
        this.emissionMetier = emissionMetier;
    }

    public String getDateEmission() {
        return dateEmission;
    }

    public void setDateEmission(String dateEmission) {
        this.dateEmission = dateEmission;
    }

    public Integer getNop() {
        return nop;
    }

    public void setNop(Integer nop) {
        this.nop = nop;
    }

    public Integer getNbordereau() {
        return nbordereau;
    }

    public void setNbordereau(Integer nbordereau) {
        this.nbordereau = nbordereau;
    }

}
```

i know that the problem i get is because of this line but i don't know what to do to fix it

```
SalaireId id = new SalaireId(e.getSalaire().getPersonnel().getCin(),e.getSalaire().getMois().getMois());
```

**edit**

EmissionDao.java

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;
import net.vo.Emission;

public interface EmissionDao {
    public List getAllEmissions();
    public List getAllEmissionsSa(Integer id,Integer m);
    public Emission getEmission(String date);
    public void insert(Emission emission);
    public void update(Emission emission);
    public void delete(String date);
}
```

EmissionHibernateDao
    package dao;

```
import java.util.List;
import net.vo.Emission;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class EmissionHibernateDao implements EmissionDao{
    private List<Emission> listeEmissions;
    private Emission emission;
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("Méthode d'initiation");
    }

    /*@Override
    public List<Object> getAllEmissions() {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("select f.idFacture,f.dateFacture,f.montantFacture,f.etatFacture,e.dateEmission,e.nop,e.nbordereau from Facture f,Emission e where e.facture = f.idFacture and f.etatFacture='émise'");
            listeEmissions = q.list();
            return listeEmissions;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }*/
    @Override
    public List getAllEmissions() {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Emission as e left join fetch e.facture as f where f.etatFacture = 'emise'");
            listeEmissions = q.list();
            return listeEmissions;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public List getAllEmissionsSa(Integer id,Integer m) {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Emission as e left join fetch e.salaire as s left join fetch s.personnel left join fetch s.mois as m where m.annee.annee =:annee and m.mois =:mois and s.etatSalaire = 'emis' ");
            q.setParameter("mois", m);
            q.setParameter("annee",id);
            listeEmissions = q.list();
            return listeEmissions;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Emission getEmission(String date) {
       Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
       try
       {    System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeee");
           session.beginTransaction();
           Query q = session.createQuery("from Emission as em where em.dateEmission='" + date +"'");
           return (Emission) q.uniqueResult();
       }
       finally
       {
           session.close();
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(Emission emission) {

      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
      Transaction tx=null;
      try
      {
          tx = session.beginTransaction();
          session.save(emission);
          tx.commit();         
      }
      catch(RuntimeException e)
      {
          if(tx != null) 
            {
                tx.rollback();
            }
          throw e;
      }
      finally
      {
          session.close();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Emission emission) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx=null;
        try
        {
            tx=session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(emission);
            tx.commit();
        }
         catch(RuntimeException e)
         {
           if(tx != null) 
            {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
         }
         finally
         {
            session.close();
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String date) {
       Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
       Transaction tx = null;
       try
       {
           tx=session.beginTransaction();
           emission = (Emission) session.get(Emission.class,date);
           session.delete(emission);
           tx.commit();
       }
       catch(RuntimeException e)
         {
            if(tx != null) 
            {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
         }
         finally
         {
            session.close();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Hibernate problem. The entity has fields declared to be lazy loaded but the entity is not attached to a valid Hibernate Session to fire the proxies to retrieve the data lazily. From the stacktrace, I cannot be sure if this error is thrown by `e.getSalaire().getPersonnel().getCin()` or `.getSalaire().getMois().getMois()` (or maybe both).

I don't know how you configured the session management, probably Spring is handling it. To solve this, you should re attach the entity to a valid Hibernate Session. You can do this by using `HibernateTemplate#refresh` method from the Spring Hibernate integration classes.

Comment: i don't know how to use hibernate template, can you explain more how i could do this. For this question i solved it using getEmission().getSalaire().getPersonnel().getCin() but i get the same problem again in another bean and it don't get fixed even if i do that.@Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: Please post how yiu define you dao classes.